# How do i get the control that is bound to a property in the ViewModel's end?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm

In WPF, how do I get the control (FrameworkElement) that is bound to a property in a viewmodel's end? I want to create a drop shodow effect on the control.

Comment: Why would you need the framework element in your presentation model? WPF styles should be capable of whatever you are trying to do according to styling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting a control instance in the ViewModel class is not really a good practice(as per MVVM). You can always have DataTrigger or converter in the XAML side to do that.